# python socket and socketserver

Tags: python, sockets, client, socketserver

I've been trying to make a multi-client server and i finally have and it works perfectly but what I want to do now is to instead of getting the clients address, get the client to type their name in and then the program will say "Bob: Hi guys" instead of "127.0.0.1: Hi guys".

I used a pre-made server and client from python docs.
Here's the server:

```
import socketserver

class MyUDPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):


    def handle(self):
        data = self.request[0].strip()
        name = self.request[0].strip()
        socket = self.request[1]
        print(name,"wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
        print(data)
        socket.sendto(data.upper(), self.client_address)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
    server = socketserver.UDPServer((HOST, PORT), MyUDPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

And here's the client:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
data = "".join(sys.argv[1:])
name = "".join(sys.argv[1:])


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

sock.sendto(bytes(name + "Bob", 'utf-8'), (HOST, PORT))
sock.sendto(bytes(data + "hello my name is Bob", "utf-8"), (HOST, PORT))
received = str(sock.recv(1024), "utf-8")

print("Sent:     {}".format(data))
print("Received: {}".format(received))
```

Everything works fine but for some reason I get this in the server once the client has connected.

```
b'Bob'  wrote:
b'Bob'
b'hello my name is bob'  wrote:
b'hello my name is bob'
```

I want it to be like:

```
Bob wrote:
b'Hello my name is bob'
```

I hope someone can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got multiple problems here.

---

The first is that you're printing `bytes` objects directly:

```
print(name,"wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
```

That's why you get `b'Bob' wrote:` instead of `Bob wrote:`. When you print a `bytes` object in Python 3, this is what happens. If you want to decode it to a string, you have to do that explicitly.

You have code that does that all over the place. It's usually cleaner to use the `decode` and `encode` methods than the `str` and `bytes` constructors, and if you're already using `format` there are even nicer ways to deal with this, but sticking with your existing style:

```
print(str(name, "utf-8"), "wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
```

---

Next, I'm not sure why you're calling `format` on a string with no format parameters, or why you're mixing multi-argument `print` functions and `format` calls together. It looks like you're trying to get `self.client_address[0]`, but you're not doing that. Then again, your desired output doesn't show it, so… just remove that `format` call if you don't want it, add a `{}` somewhere in the format string if you do. (You're also probably going to want to decode `client_address[0]`, too.)

---

Next, you store the same value in `name` and `data`:

```
data = self.request[0].strip()
name = self.request[0].strip()
```

So, when you later do this:

```
print(data)
```

… that's just printing `name` again—and, again, without decoding it. So, even if you fix the decoding problem, you'll still get this:

```
Bob wrote:
Bob
```

… instead of just:

```
Bob wrote:
```

To fix that, just get rid of the `data` variable and the `print(data)` call.

---

Next, you're sending two separate packets, one with the `name` and the other with the `data`, but trying to recover both out of each packet. So, even if you fix all of the above, you're going to get `Bob` in one packet as the name, and `hello my name is bob` in the next packet, resulting in:

```
Bob wrote:
hello my name is bob wrote:
```

If you want this to be stateful, you need to actually store the state somewhere. In your case, the state is incredibly simple—just a flag saying whether this is the first message from a given client—but it still has to go somewhere. One solution is to associate a new state with each address using a dictionary—although in this case, since the state is either "seen before" or nothing at all, we can just use a set.

Putting it all together:

```
class MyUDPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.seen = set()
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)

    def handle(self):
        data = self.request[0].strip()
        addr = self.client_address[0]
        if not addr in self.seen:
            print(str(data, "utf-8"), "wrote:")
            self.seen.add(addr)
        else:
            print(str(data, "utf-8"))
        socket.sendto(data.upper(), self.client_address)
```

---

Meanwhile, it seems like what you *actually* want is to store the name from the first request as your per-client state, so you can reuse it in every future request. That's almost as easy. For example:

```
class MyUDPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.clients = {}
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)

    def handle(self):
        data = str(self.request[0].strip(), 'utf-8')
        addr = self.client_address[0]
        if not addr in self.clients:                
            print(data, "joined!")
            self.clients[addr] = data
        else:
            print(self.clients[addr], 'wrote:', data)
        socket.sendto(data.upper(), self.client_address)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining what I had been doing wrong, I have now corrected the code and it works how I want it to now.

Comment: When I used the code that you added last it started perfectly but when I try to get a client to connect to the server I get this:

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given

@abarnert

Comment: @user2387537: OK, edited to pass through any arguments given to `__init__`, which will solve that problem.

Comment: I have another error now, because of `myUPDHandler` it says this: `if not addr in self.clients:
AttributeError: 'MyUDPHandler' object has no attribute 'clients' ` @abarnert

Comment: @user2387537: OK, maybe the constructor calls `handle` before returning or something. Just move the `self.clients = {}` above the `super` call, as in the edited version. But you're going to need to understand the basics of how classes work in Python well enough to debug this kind of thing yourself, or this code isn't going to be any good for you.

Comment: That has kind of worked but not going to ask anymore questions and I would try and find out how they worked but I don't know where to find  out how to. @abarnert

Comment: Do you know how to find the tutorial, reference docs, and howtos in the Python documentation? Start there. If you get stuck, try to come up with a specific, easily-answerable question, and search on this and similar sites to see if anyone else has already asked it. If not, put together a good complete question (the one you posted this time was good) and ask it as a new question here.

Comment: Yes I do. OK thank you for telling me the right information I needed.